# Large factorial series

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have to print series :-

```
n*(n-1),n*(n-1)*(n-2),n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3),n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*(n-4)...,n!.
```

Problem is large value of n , it can go upto 37 and n! will obviously go out of bounds ?
I just cant get started , please help , how would you have tackled situation if you were in my place ?

Comment: Is this from Al Zimmermann's Programming Contests ( http://www.azspcs.net/ )?

Comment: Did you forget (n-2) in n*(n-1)*(n-3)*(n-4) or is that intentional?

Comment: 37! needs 143 bits, too much for most traditional programming languages. You could use the unix tool "bc" (http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/) which handles arbitrary precision. Languages like C# have "BigInteger" data type for such problems.

Comment: @WolframH : Yes i was asking this for azspcs contest but here i have asked an open question handling big nos. series , so no one should think that i am cheating like Ted has said already ;)

Comment: @AxelKemper : I forgot to mention that i was working in c/c++ :)

Comment: @Martinsos : Oops xD Yeah it was mistake on my part , i will correct it , thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the language you are using. Some languages automatically switch to a large integer package when numbers get too large for the machine's native integer representation. In other languages, just use a large integer library, which should handle 37! easily.

Wikipedia has a [list of arbitrary-precision arithmetic libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries) for some languages. There are also lots of other resources on the web.

Comment: Preferbly , c/c++ but you may tell of any language :)
And cant we do without these precision libraries ? Because like in contests if i were supposed to handle this big calculation then libraries cant come to my rescue-they are not allowed ?

Comment: @AdamSmith - I suspect that for the contest, an analytic, rather than a computational, approach is required. That is, the trick is to discover a straight line program through reasoning--and to prove that it is correct through reasoning (most likely induction). In particular, being able to compute 37! isn't actually going to help you find a competitive SLP. In general, though, handling numbers larger than will fit in a native integer type (typically at most 64 or 128 bits) will require a large number package.

Comment: yeah i agree with you but using this computational approach , i can easily score atleast 10 points ! And thats quite nice for a school boy :D I was thinking to first get the free points that i can , like i have O(2(n+1)) solution in general case and thought to fully utilize this algo to get points freely in reach then try for optimization with better approaches/algorithm/technique :)

Answer (score 1):

3 year old problem looked fun.

Simple create a routine to "multiply" a string by a *factor*.  Not highly efficient, yet gets the job done.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void mult_array(char *x, unsigned factor) {
  unsigned accumulator = 0;
  size_t n = strlen(x);
  size_t i = n;
  while (i > 0) {
    i--;
    accumulator += (unsigned)(x[i]-'0')*factor;
    x[i] = (char) (accumulator%10 + '0');
    accumulator /= 10;
  }
  while (accumulator > 0) {
    memmove(x+1, x, ++n);
    x[i] = (char) (accumulator%10 + '0');
    accumulator /= 10;
  }
}

#include <stdio.h>
void AS_Factorial(unsigned n) {
  char buf[1000]; // Right-size buffer (problem for another day)
  sprintf(buf, "%u", n);
  fputs(buf, stdout);
  while (n>1) {
    n--;
    mult_array(buf, n);
    printf(",%s", buf);
  }
  puts("");
}
```

Sample usage and output

```
int main(void) {
  AS_Factorial(5);
  AS_Factorial(37);
  return 0;
}

5,20,60,120,120
37,1332,46620,1585080,52307640,1673844480,...,13763753091226345046315979581580902400000000
```

Comment: (Before long, you will have reinveted "packed BCD-arithmetic".)

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) in Java and it works.

Working code for demonstration purpose:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Factorial {
    public static int[] primes = {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37};
    public static BigInteger computeFactorial(int n) {
        if (n==0) {
            return new BigInteger(String.valueOf(1));
        } else {
            return new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n)).multiply(computeFactorial(n-1));
        }
    }
    public static String getPowers(int n){
        BigInteger input = computeFactorial(n);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.length && input.intValue() != 1;) {
            BigInteger[] result = input.divideAndRemainder(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(primes[i])));
            if (result[1].intValue() == 0) {
                input = input.divide(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(primes[i])));
                count++;
                if (input.intValue() == 1) {sb.append(primes[i] + "(" + count + ") ");}
            } else {
                if (count!=0)
                sb.append(primes[i] + "(" + count + ") ");
                count = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getPowers(37));
    }
}
```

Feel free to use it without worrying about copyright if you want.

**Update**: I didn't realize you were using C++ until now. In that case, you can give [boost BigInteger](http://code.google.com/p/cpputils/source/browse/0.6/cpputils/include/cpputils/exttypes/BigInteger.hpp?r=c62b5ae5ec96fa6373805e96c52397f853ec8a5e) a try.

Comment: Never mind , it was my fault that i didnt mention c++ first ^_^
But a big big thanks Terry Li , votes up :)

Comment: @AdamSmith The compiler online was complaining and asking you to remove the first `public` keyword in the code, which is not an issue if you compile it in a file named `Factorial.java` on your own computer.

Comment: Thanks once again but the output is not what i expected :) My series is entirly different Terry ,say for 4 , my series is 12,24 ! REASON:4*3,4*3*2. For 13 it would be (13*12),(13*12*11),(13*12*11*10) and so on. , would be printed as 156,1716,17160 and so on. I had got programs to calculate big factorials as large as 100 but they used array of char to store so , i couldnt multiply two factorials !
Thanks again for extending helping hand :)

Comment: @AdamSmith My code just demonstrated a way to hold very large integers and was not intended to solve your specific problem. I guess you want to figure the rest out on your own : )

Answer (score 0):

You may use big integer, but however this still has some limitations, but even though, this datatype can handle a very large value. The value that the big integer can hold, ranges from
-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 for the signed big integer, and 
0 to 18446744073709551615 for the unsigned big integer.

If you really plan to do some bigger value computation which is bigger than the big integer data type, why not try the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/)?

As from what the site says, "GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating point numbers. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of functions, and the functions have a regular interface." - gmplib.org

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own big-integer type if it's not permitted to use any thirdparty libraries. You can do something like that:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    const int base = 1000 * 1000 * 1000; // base value, should be the power of 10
    const int lbase = 9; // lg(base)

    void output_biginteger(vector<int>& a) {
      cout << a.back();
      for (int i = (int)a.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        cout << setw(lbase) << setfill('0') << a[i];
      cout << endl;
    }

    void multiply_biginteger_by_integer(vector<int>& a, int b) {
      int carry = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.size(); ++i) {
        long long cur = (long long)a[i] * b + carry;
        carry = cur / base;
        a[i] = cur % base;
      }
      if (carry > 0) {
        a.push_back(carry);
      }
    }

    int main() {
      int n = 37; // input your n here
      vector<int> current(1, n);
      for (int i = n - 1; n >= 1; --n) {
        multiply_biginteger_by_integer(current, i);
        output_biginteger(current);
      }
      return 0;
    }
```